# Batch file to search for and delete lines containing specific text

Tags: batch, csv

I have a bat file that searches a directory for specific .csv files names, and copies and amends the lines into a new .csv file.

However, some of the lines of the original .csv files are not information needed, and begin with **PO-**.  I'd like to add to my bat a way to search for cells containing **"PO-"** and delete the entire line, and then save the results in a new .csv file.  Is it possible?.

What I have so far in my .bat file is:

```
REM

@ Echo off

Echo on

type NUL>fdx.csv

copy pds*.csv fdx.csv
```

Comment: It would help if you were to post your batch file code.

Comment: Do you want a .bat file or a macro for excel? You have both tagged.

Comment: Sorry new to all of this.  I'd like a .bat file. 

What I have in my .bat already is:
type NUL>fdx.csv

copy pds*.csv fdx.csv

Echo on

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use FIND

```
find /V "PO-" fdx.csv > new.csv
```

but you will get a header on the csv file that you have to remove manually

Answer (score 1):

FINDSTR will work better;

```
findstr /v /i /b "PO-" fdx.csv > new.csv
```

/v will exclude lines with "PO-"

/b will only look for PO- at the beginning of the line

/i will make it case-insensitive (so Po-, po- pO-)

Or, with FIND, you could use MORE +x to skip x lines and remove the header it leaves behind;

```
more +1 | find /v "PO-" fdx.csv > new.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

type fdx.csv | find /V "PO-" > new.csv

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer,  but made more complicated with no benefit.